# Switch from Anaconda 64-bit to 32-bit installation but keep libraries installed

Tags: python, anaconda

Is it possible to do the above switch in any particularly neat way? I'm a bit afraid of breaking the quite long list of modules that have been installed.

Comment: You have to install them again. Nothing will break for a module if it's a platform independend, but many modules are dependant on a system version. With cPython you'd probably save output of `pip freeze` to a file `requirements.txt` and then run `pip install -r requirements.txt` on a new python version. Unfortunately, I'm not so familiar with Anaconda to write it as an answer

Comment: The equivalent conda command is `conda env export`